# Change styling / CSS in Cross domain iFrame (using "iFrame Resizer")

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, postmessage

Hope not to get too much flak for my noob question! :-)

I would reeeeeally like an example of how to do the following:

I own two domains - domain A and domain B.

I'd like to display an iframe on domain B with a page from domain A ..but with different CSS (removing header, footer etc.)

At the moment I am using "Iframe Resizer" (https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer) to automatically fit the iframe on domain B. This works great!

I just can't get a grip on either SENDING different styling from domain A or on MODIFYING the styling in the iFrame on domain B.

This is the code I currnetly have on domain A:

```
<!-- Scripts for resizing iFrame SEND -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri();?>/js/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js" defer></script>

    <script>

        //EITHER A TRIGGER OR A MESSAGE CONTAINING CSS TO SEND TO DOMAIN B...

    </script>

<!-- Scripts for resizing iFrame SEND -->
```

..and this is the code I currently have on domain B:

```
    <!-- Scripts for resizing iFrame RECIEVE -->

        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri();?>/js/iframeResizer.min.js"></script>

        <iframe style="border: none;" id="asc" src="http://domainA.com/example" width="100%" scrolling="no"></iframe>

        <script>

            iFrameResize({log:false}, '#asc')

            //A RECEIVER FOR THE TRIGGER / CSS FROM DOMAIN A RESULTING IN MODIFIED STYLING OF THE IFRAME CONTENT

        </script>

    <!-- Scripts for resizing iFrame RECIEVE -->
```

Thanks a zillion in advance to anyone who can help me out with this (most likely) simple piece of code! :-)

Comment: You can't inherit CSS from domain B for the iframe embedded directly. You can use jQuery to get the stylesheet and add it to iframe or a better solution will be to create a new page on domain A with all the styles required and then embed it as iframe on domain B

Comment: Thanks for the comment @KiranDash ..but creating seperate pages on domain A with different stylesheets is not an option :-/

This is because there are several pages on domain A that I need to display on domain B, so instead of creating 30 new pages, I "only" need to make slight changes to the CSS on all of them, when they are displayed in the iFrame on domain B. 

I was hoping that "Window.postmessage()" (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) could be a solution to pass the CSS ..but I don't know if it's the way to go (doable/secure?) and I don't know how

Comment: You might achieve with a little `jQuery`. Have a look at my answer below. I hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Create a stylesheet on domainB that has styles only for the `iframe` that you want to use and then append it to your iframe with jQuery.

**Code:**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#iframeFromDomainA').load(function(){
        $('#iframeFromDomainA')
            .contents().find("head")
            .append($('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.domainb.com/css/styleforiframeonwebsiteb.css">')
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks again Kiran ...but can't seem to get it to work. Are you sure it's possible to append / change the css in the iFrame on the receiving domainB? 

A thought here is: it's possible to send window size back and forth. Is it perhaps possible to send the css FROM domainB back to the host domainA and then use it there just for the content of the iframe? 

Again I don't have a clue as to what's possible and best practice here :-)

Comment: do you know if it is possible (and how) to send the css FROM domain B and back to domain A (maybe with "postmessage") and if this is a solution?